# Installed eterm but it is not in my path

Tags: 10.04, kubuntu

I'm trying to install eterm on an instance of Kubuntu.

I `sudo apt-get install eterm`, and everything seems to go alright, but at the end there's no eterm on my path.

Anyone know where the stuff got hidden so I can link the executable to somewhere on my path.

Comment: My assumption is that if you open a terminal and type `eterm`, the response indicates that it can't find 'eterm'.  Have you gone into the Synaptic Package Manager and determined where 'eterm' was installed?  If not installed in a directory currently in your path, you can either add the location to you path, or create a symbolic link in a directory that is in your path.

Answer (score 4):

The file to execute is `Eterm`, as you can see with the command:

```
dpkg -L eterm | grep bin
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find the path with `find / -name "eterm"` and then append the folder to your PATH by adding `export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/eterm/folder` to your `.bashrc`.